# Why are we using docker-registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, openshift-origin

Can someone explain me 'Docker-registry'?
I face it in OpenShift but it's hard to understand what it is at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Docker Registry](http://hub.docker.com/) is where you push and pull images.  When you go `docker pull {myimagename}` you are pulling from the Docker Registry.  Likewise, when you go `docker push {username}/{imagename}` you are pushing to the Docker Registry.  The Docker Registry is available as a public or private registry.  The public is available at [hub.docker.com](http://hub.docker.com/) and the private is available for purchase from [docker.com](http://docker.com).  There is also a free open source version of the registry available on [github.com](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry), though the open source version has been deprecated and is being replaced by the Docker Trusted Registry.

Comment: and what's the difference with an image stream?

Comment: ImageStream is Openshifts own Docker Registry.  Most likely running on the deprecated v1 API as the v2 API and registry are for purchase only when run on prem.

Comment: OpenShift uses the open source v2 registry which is not deprecated.  The registry is backed by OpenShift storage but exposes the Docker V2 registry API

Comment: So the initial docker registry contains an image repository which contains your images? From here you can push and pull to Docker Hub? And you can also create an imageStream so your docker registry can pull it's image from there instead of Docker Hub. Am I right?

Comment: @Anonymous yes. You can either push or pull from docker hub or from imageStream which is acting as a private repository.